# "lib64/R/include: No such file or directory" error

Tags: r, installation, updates, rcpp

I have recently updated to R version 4.0.0. However, after updating, it is failed to install new packages, take "Rcpp" as example. The error message said that "lib64/R/include: No such file or directory". The directory did exist, actually.

The updated version is installed into the exact same directory as the old version by using `--prefix` parameter at `configure` step.

When I encounter this problem, I have tried and found:

1. reinstalling the R-4.0.0 into the same directory after removing the old version. But the error message still there.
2. some packages have the same problem, including `testthat`.
3. some packages don't have this problem, can be successfully installed, including `tibble`.
4. back to R version 3.6.1. `Rcpp` can be successfully installed.

Thank you!

```
> BiocManager::install("Rcpp")
Bioconductor version 3.11 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Installing package(s) 'Rcpp'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2751467 bytes (2.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.6 MB

* installing *source* package 'Rcpp' ...
** package 'Rcpp' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
I"/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/     -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-macro-redefined -c api.cpp -o api.o
/bin/sh: I/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [api.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I"/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/     -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-macro-redefined -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
/bin/sh: I/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [attributes.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I"/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/     -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-macro-redefined -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
/bin/sh: I/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [barrier.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I"/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/     -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-macro-redefined -c date.cpp -o date.o
/bin/sh: I/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [date.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I"/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/     -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-macro-redefined -c module.cpp -o module.o
/bin/sh: I/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [module.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I"/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/include/ -I/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/include/     -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-macro-redefined -c rcpp_init.cpp -o rcpp_init.o
/bin/sh: I/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [rcpp_init.o] Error 127 (ignored)
-L/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/lib -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/xz-5.2.2/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/ncurses-5.8/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/readline-6.3/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/zlib-1.2.8/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/bzip2-1.0.6/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre-8.39/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/pcre2-10.34/lib/ -L/path/to/soft/lib/packages/curl-7.52.1/lib/ -o Rcpp.so api.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o -L/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/lib -lR
/bin/sh: line 2: -L/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/lib: No such file or directory
make: *** [Rcpp.so] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcpp'
* removing '/path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/library/Rcpp'

The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/RtmpM3149V/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Old packages: 'KernSmooth', 'MASS', 'boot', 'class', 'foreign', 'nnet',
  'spatial'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: n
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit status
```

The system information listed below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /path/to/soft/R/R_soft/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0
```

Comment: Sorry you are having trouble but that issue may be local to you and your lab setup -- see the (mostly) clean bill of health at CRAN incl two Fedora systems:  https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_Rcpp.html

Comment: Also:  Simplify! Instead of `BiocManager::install("Rcpp")`, maybe stick with `install.packages("Rcpp")`.  Then test it:  `Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")`.  If that works as expected your problems are then with other packages.

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel I will have a try. Best!